# How to add custom keywords or aliases to Monaco Editor at runtime

Tags: azure-data-explorer, monaco-editor

I am working with the Monaco Editor, specifically using the kusto language support [monaco-kusto](https://github.com/Azure/monaco-kusto). I am trying to replicate functionality inside Azure Data Explorer (ADX) which contains an editor for kusto and it allows you to define 2 placeholders (_startTime and _endTime) which are augmented using a dropdown selector.

Now, in my own project I have everything working except for the keyword recognition of those names. I am not sure what ADX does, whether its got a custom build of the kusto library or there is some way in Monaco that you are able to add custom keywords to get over the error highlighting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at the Grafana implementation of a similar functionality here:

https://github.com/grafana/azure-data-explorer-datasource/tree/main/src/editor

Comment: Perfect thanks, this is what I needed. Adding custom functions for my keywords did the trick.